# Prove that for $n\ge 6$ there is always a solution

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

We have the eation $\frac{1}{a_1^2} + \frac{1}{a_2^2}+...+\frac{1}{a_n^2}=1$. Prove that the equation has for $n\ge 6$ always natural solutions.

Any $\frac{1}{x^2}$ can be displayed as sum of 4 numbers displayed as $\frac{1}{(2x)^2}$. So induction we can show that if it holds for $n$ then it holds for $n+3$.

Comment: Any work on your part?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Then it remains to show **one** solution for $n=6,7$ and $8$.

Comment: $$n=6: (2,2,2,3,3,6);$$ $$n=7: (2,2,2,4,4,4,4);$$ $$n=8: (2,2,3,3,3,3,6,6) \mbox { and others}.$$